# Black borders on: windows, notifications, menus, etc

Tags: unity, graphics, compiz, intel-graphics, window-decoration

I'm getting a black border around all elements in unity desktop. With terminal window is all black.

If I maximize a window I get the name of it and normal actions

Tried:

- running: dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && setsid unity
- removing .compiz .config/compiz-1
- reseting unity
- create a new user and test against him

Compiz runs as normal with this exception. glxinfo says that direct rendering is active.

Graphics:
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)

Any suggestion is welcome!

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I upgraded some libdrm-* libraries with a ppa and after removing the ppa I missed some downgrades.

Fixed them and now I got the window decorations back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

> "Solved it. I upgraded some libdrm-* libraries with a ppa..."

I also had a problem with "black borders". Tried various actions to reset Compiz, Unity, but with no effect due to various errors. Wherein I forgot that I just installed Intel Graphics driver, and that installation has finished incorrectly. When I installed Intel Graphics driver again without errors, and rebooted my Ubuntu, black borders have gone.